# Why is arginine's positive side chain classified as basic and not acidic?

Tags: acid-base, biochemistry, amino-acids

Arginine has a positive side chain.

Doesn't this mean it wants to lose a proton **H+**? Isn't something that wants to lose or donate a proton an acid?

Yet my book states, "arginine has a positively charged side chain, i.e it is
basic" .

[image: Arginine]

Comment: Protonated arginine sidechain makes a *weak acid*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your textbook is imprecise. We consider whether a sidechain is acidic or basic based on the action of the sidechain *when it is neutral*.

Because arginine's sidechain is basic, it preferentially picks up a proton, and hence becomes positively charged. (In the same vein, carboxylic acid sidechains are acidic because they preferentially lose a proton, and exist as the negatively charged carboxylate anion.)

Comment: I would use "uncharged" instead of "neutral" to avoid confusion but otherwise +1